# JFrog Artifactory - how to upload symlinks properly and download the destination

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I have the following artifactory repo and directory structure:

```
my-repository/binaries/binary.file
my-repository/dir1/
my-repository/dir2/
...
```

I would like to do add a symlink of binary.file in dir1 and dir2.
Assuming that I've added binary.file as follows:

```
$ jfrog rt u binary.file my-repository/binaries/binary.file
```

So here's where I fail to understand the concept of symlinks in artifactory.
I've created the same directory structure on the local filesystem and created a symlink:

```
$ find .
./my-repository/
./my-repository/binaries/
./my-repository/binaries/binary.file
./my-repository/dir1/
./my-repository/dir2/
$ cd my-repository/dir1/
$ ln -s ../binaries/binary.file .
$ jfrog rt u --symlinks binary.file my-repository/dir1/
...
$ cd /tmp
$ jfrog rt dl --validate-symlinks my-repository/dir1/binary.file
 Log path: /home/user/.jfrog/logs/jfrog-cli.2020-04-09.18-42-13.19989.log
{
  "status": "failure",
  "totals": {
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1
  }
}
[Error] Download finished with errors, please review the logs.
$ cat /home/user/.jfrog/logs/jfrog-cli.2020-04-09.18-42-13.19989.log
[Info] Searching items to download...
[Info] [Thread 2] Downloading my-repository/dir1/binary.file
[Error] Symlink validation failed, target doesn't exist: ../binaries/binary.file
```

If I remove the --validate-symlinks argument, then an empty file gets downloaded. What is the proper way of uploading symlinks and vice-versa, downloading such? Is there a way to download the destination file by using a symlink?

Comment: I've just tried exactly what you did, and after downloading the symlink (using the "jfrog rt dl" command), I saw that the symlink got created locally, as expected. I tried this with the latest release of JFrog CLI.To troubleshoot the issue, before downloading the file, try searching for it (using the "jfrog rt s" command) and see that the file has the "symlink.dest" and "symlink.destsha1" properties, which indicate that this file was indeed uploaded as a symlink. The "jfrog rt dl" command should pick up those properties, and create this file as a symlink locally. LMK what you see.

Comment: The file got uploaded successfully, it's just that the symlink.dest attribute is not set accordingly or something else is wrong.

Comment: Which JFrog CLI version are you using? Could it be a version that predates the symlinks support? The latest version as of today is 1.35.3.

Comment: I should not that my "example" was slightly edited from the original use-case, as I had to make it more neutral for stackoverflow. Perhaps that was a mistake in a way and I didn't do it as good as the actual use-case. I'm also using JFrog 1.35.3. The only difference from the actual use-case is that I'm using a deeper directory.